# Why won't my systemd REDIS service start in RHEL 7.9?

Tags: redis, systemd, rhel7

So I'm not sure how to even figure out what's happening.  Running redis-server version 6.2.5 on RHEL 7.9.  I can start REDIS with the user I want to run it as from the command line.  But when  I try to start it as a systemd service with the REDIS.service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=REDIS Service
After=syslog.target network.target remote-fs.target nss-lookup.target
[Service]
Type=simple
User=myuser
Group=myuser
WorkingDirectory=/app/redis
ExecStart=/bin/redis-server /app/redis/primary.conf
Restart=on-failure
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

It fails.  The journalctl entry shows:

> Aug 27 08:57:18 computerName redis-server[119338]: 119338:C 27 Aug 2021
> 08:57:18.981 # Fatal error, can't open config file
> '/app/redis/primary.conf': Permission denied

The redis directory and all of it's files are owned by the user I'm telling to run the service.  I even went to the extent of putting 777 on the directory and files.  Thanks for any help you can give me!

Eric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This server was a mess.  There was previous install of redis on the server, the rpm database was corrupt, there were old services that weren't running but were still there.  I had to do a lot of cleanup and perform a clean install and it started working.